# What is the simplest way to get an inverse function?

Tags: function, inverse

I need to use the inverse of a linear function of an error function in a code. What would be the simplest way to get an inverse of such a function in python?

Answer (score 2):

y = mx + t
x = (y - t) / m = y/m - t/m

m is slope, t is y-axis section.
The first one is the linear function, the second one is the inversed linear function.
You just have to translate this into python now.